# UITableViewCell Row Height Changes Flicker - Font Sizes

Tags: ios, uitableview, font-size, adaptive-layout

I am using adaptive layout, and cannot find a solution to this simple problem.

While setting the text size for iphone to 18px, and the ipad to 24px for a Basic Tableview cell. Like this

[image]

I initially get the large font, and cell row height which then refreshes to the expected height after a second or so. When using an iPhone, using the iPad is fine.

When I remove this from in viewDidLoad is works as expected.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

However, this is required, as without it when I push and pop to a detail view, the cells resize and cause a weird / ugly effect as it goes off screen.

Any ideas ?

Thanks